# Android / Java: Arraylist return value which contains a word

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm building an app where i load an arraylist of URLs from an external XML (the arraylist is created by JSoup parsing).
Then, i need to:

1. Check if a certain word is present in one of the string in arraylist
   (the URLs);
2. Return the string which contains the given value (the URL which
   contain my word).

For managing the `Arraylist.contains()` i found the following sample code, that i'm implementing; but the following codes will return a printout sentence, not the value.
How can i set the code to return the string which contains the given word?

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2178228925760279677L;

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        int size = this.size(); 
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
                if (this.get(i) == null) {
                    return i; 
                }
            }
        } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
                if (this.get(i).contains(String.valueOf(o))) {
                    return i; 
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Here to use it:

```
MyArrayList arrayList = new MyArrayList(); 
arrayList.add("http://www.google.com");
arrayList.add("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
arrayList.add("http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com");

if (arrayList.contains("google")) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList Contains google word");
}
```

I need the result to be: `System.out.println("The URL which contains my word");`

Thanks for your availabiliy

Comment: use foreach loop and check which item contains the url...

Comment: Could you kindly post a code sample where i can start (in the answer)? If it works, i will be happy to flag it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i commented here is the code for that:

```
for (String string : arrayList) {
        if (string.contains("stackoverflow")) {
        System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I test it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the whole length of the arraylist:-

```
for(i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++)
{
if (arrayList.get(i).contains("google")) 
{
System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
}
else
{//your code
 }}
```

i am assuming here that your arraylist contains string elements

Comment: But the output of your code is "ArrayList Contains google word", not the value i need.

Comment: Thanks for your contribuition. I test it and let you know

Comment: Your answer is correct but i choose the other one because it's simpler to implement. In any case, i upvoted your answer. Thanks for your support